# Send and Read from a socket simultaneously

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm working on a simple proxy server. The problem is browser sometimes re-uses the connection and sends multiple requests on the same connection.

I'm using TcpClient and Stream to make HTTP request to the server. How can I have read and write functions 'separate' from each other, like in separate threads for example. Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track.  You'll need separate threads for reading and writing in order to handle simultaneous transfers.  An alternative would be to use the asynchronous features of `HttpWebRequest` on the client side.  I'm not quite sure of what the server side equivalent would be.

Answer (score 2):

Its called persistent connection. If you don't want the browser to do that, you should not send this header "Connection: Keep-Alive" in your proxy response.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: Thanks! That's actually how I'm doing it now, but I want browser to re-use connection.